# QR-Code generation EPS with own image

Tags: php, qr-code, eps

I would like to know if somebody knows a library where I can create an QR-Code and embedd my own image or logo in it.

Export should be EPS with YCMK.

I've found this one here
http://code.google.com/p/zend-framework-matrixcode-module/
but don't really know if it could work with it...

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written a [QR generator in PHP](https://github.com/alister/QR-Generator-PHP/) which will output in PNG, JPG, or GIF.

I would suggest using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to add the logo and convert to EPS.

**Note** - make sure you use the H (high) level of error correction. As Wandera Nauta says, that will give you 30% redundancy.  A small central logo shouldn't "damage" the code too much. Make sure to avoid covering the three corner squares.

Here's an example code with an image in the middle.

[image: QR code with Logo]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against trying this.

The QR standard is built to resist a large amount of damage. Every QR code contains a lot of 'extra' data that can be used for error recovery, which means your phone will properly scan a QR code even if a chunk is missing.

That feature can be used (or abused, depending how you look at it) to replace parts of the image with your own image or logo. This is probably what you were looking for, however, it's difficult if not impossible to know in advance if the resulting image will be good enough to scan, other than manual trial-and-error (while outside, in rainy conditions, with a cheap phone camera).

You're basically throwing a major feature of QR away for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: _throwing a major feature of QR away for aesthetic reasons_ yeah I know. But using the 30% error correction gives enough space to 'miss'use it for company logos. And if you keep the image small enough, you'll always be under that rate...

Answer (score 2):

Be carefull, if you want a vector EPS export first you have to use a qr code library that exports vector EPS and then you can't use ImageMagick since it will raster your vector image (see [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector)).

For the first point, you should use the library you found which can export true vector files.

For the second point, I've no solution for you yet. Maybe you could try processing raw EPS (since it's text) to insert programatically your logo.

Comment: why not merge images first and then create the EPS?

Comment: As I said, the problem is if you want to have true vector files (Assuming that your logo is also a vector file). If you merge it using imageMagick, it will always raster both filesand it will be pixels. That's why I also said that you could try processing raw eps and merge the files directly but it might be really complicated :s

Comment: I read the link and know the limitations now. But it's actually possible to get EPS from it. But the result is not true vector. This is supposed to be a small tool to at least make it work and it seems it does work. Quality is the issue. I'll have to try to see how it looks...